# Uniform convergence sufficient conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, function-spaces

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of continuous functions defined in a compact interval C, so that $f_n$ converges to $f$ pointwise. Show that $f_n$ is uniformly convergent to $f$ if and only if:

**1)** $f$ is continuous on C.

**2)** $\forall\epsilon>0 ,\exists \delta>0,\exists N\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $n\geq N$ and $|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\delta$   implies $|f_{k+n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall x\in C$ and $\forall k\in \mathbb{N}$.

I think I'm able to prove it if $\delta\geq\epsilon$, in the same way that Dini's theorem is proved, showing that if $|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$ then $|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\delta$, so $|f_{k+n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$. Then we can proceed in the same way as the [standard proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_theorem), since $E(_{jN})$ is ascending ($x\in E_k \rightarrow x\in E_{k+N}$). Is this correct?

I can't figure out the case $\delta<\epsilon$, any help would be aprecciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that your problem is about the implication: 1) and 2) implies uniformly convergence.

You can proceed also as follow:

Using you notation and fixing $\epsilon>0$:

for any $x \in C$ there exists $k_x$ such that $|f_{k_x}(x)-f(x)|<\delta$, an open neighborhood $U_{x}$ of $x$ such that $|f_{k_x}(y)-f(y)|<\delta$ is verified in $U_{x}$, and thanks to 2) there exists $N_x$ such that:

$$|f_k(x)-f(x)|<\delta$$

implies

$$|f_{n}(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon, \forall n \geq N_x$$

Thus for all $y \in U_{x}$
$$|f_{n}(y)-f(y)|<\epsilon, \forall n \geq N_x$$

Thanks to the fact that $C$ is compact, you can exctract a finite number of such $U_{x_i}$ and then take $N=\max_{i} N_{x_i}$. Then you have that for all $x \in C$, for all $n \geq N$:

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$$

Comment: By definition of $g_n$ I think it has to be decreasing. Also, how does it converge to $f$ pointwise? I'm not sure if I did understand how you define it well. Is it $g_n(x)=\inf_{k\leq n} f_k(x)$?

Comment: I have edited it.

Comment: Ok, now it is clear that $g_n$  converges to f, it is nondecreasing and continuous, so it converges uniformly. I've been trying but I don't see how that implies that $f_n$ also does, other than doing the same with the supremum and bounding $f_n$ between the two. And that's clearly not correct because it wouldn't require 1) and 2).

Comment: Now I see that $g_n$ is not necessarily continuous without 1) and 2). So I suppose that 1) and 2) must imply that it is continuous, but I can't figure out the proof. Could you give any hints?

Comment: @Nonimous I have edited the answer. Tell me if it is not clear.

Comment: I understand the proof, but I think there might be some misspells. Didn't you mean $g_n(y)\leq g_n(x)$?, and also I think there should be an $x$ in the $\sup$ expression.

Comment: However, how is this possible only with continuity of $f_k$? For example, the sequence $f_n(x)=nx\big(1-x^2\big)^n,\quad x\in[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$  is continuous for all n but the the supremum functions are not continuous on 0, and it also converges to a continuous function (0) pointwise in a compact interval, so even with those hyphotesis it is still not necessarily continuous. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: In your counterexample I think that the supremuum is continuos in 0. 1) and 2) are to be used to prove the fact that the new sequence converges to $f$

Comment: I did not prove it, but if you graph the functions you can see that there is a peak that aproachs infinity when n does, and it gets closer and closer to 0 in the x axis, so I think the supremum function tends to infinity when x aproachs 0. Also, I don't think we need 1) and 2) to prove pointwise convergence, since if $n\geq N \rightarrow |f_n(x) - f(x) | <\epsilon/2$ implies $|g_n(x) - f(x) |<\epsilon$, right?

Comment: Another example would be $f_n(x)=x^n,\quad x\in[0,1]\subset\mathbb{R}$ with a discontinuity of the infimus function on 1

Comment: @Nonimous I edited again. I hope it will help you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107513/discussion-between-nonimous-and-filippo-giovagnini).